# angular 11 handle http response

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Guess this might be basic but I'm a complete angular and observable beginner.
Trying to follow the angular official Heroes tutorial which in the end uses an in-memory api to mock a real server; I am hooking my example with a real backend but unsure how to handle the data returned from the server properly.

I have a `HeroService`, there is a method to get all heroes. I am using angular's `HttpClient` and by design my server returns a single object with a `results` property, which itself is an array. How can I convert the `results` property in the response to an `Observable` of `Hero[]`? By the way, each element in `results` property has the same shape as the defined `Hero` interface.

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    var res: Hero[] = []
    return this.http.get("https://my_heroes_url", this.httpOptions)
            .pipe(x => x['results'] as Hero[]);
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`map` RxJS operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map):

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get("https://my_heroes_url", this.httpOptions)
            .pipe(map(x => x['results'] as Hero[]));
}
```

For more information about RxJS operators, consider taking a look at the [RxJS manual on operators](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#operators).

Comment: knew this was basic; thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: I see there is a `filter` operator but when I try to use it on `Observable<Hero[]>` it doesn't work. How to filter an observable of a collection?

Comment: @stt106 Call `.pipe` again with the operator.